# Can someone appear to have sent an email and place it in the Sent Mail folder?

Tags: gmail

If an email is seen in Gmail’s *Sent Mail* folder, should it not match the same email in the inbox folder?

Can an email appear to be sent in the folder but not sent?

Answer (score 1):

There are two situations:

1. If it was sent as an individual email and not as a reply to a previously received one, it should be in the *Sent Mail* folder and only there.
2. If it’s a reply to an *Inbox* email (which I assume you are referring to), it depends on whether you deleted or archived the email in the *Inbox*. If you archived the email/conversation, the sent email is still visible in the *Sent Mail* folder, but the original is no longer visible in *Inbox*. Likewise, if you sent the reply but deleted the email (**not** the conversation, but the individual email) in *Inbox*, then, again, the sent one will be still visible in the *Sent Mail* folder while there is nothing visible in *Inbox*.